# Div's Positioning Change on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four Div's one after the other inside a main div and aligned vertically.

Like:

```
DIV1
DIV2
DIV3
DIV4
```

I want that clicking on any of the DIV, the div whose is clicked comes on the top and the other slide down. How can i do it using jQuery?

E.g.

If DIV3 was clicked the divs reorder themselves like this:

```
DIV3
DIV1
DIV2
DIV4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, consider using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for live examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vertical animated version, that is relatively positioned and fairly flexible.

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/RgGyF/

Comment: Nice code. I created a [fork that uses event delegation](http://jsfiddle.net/hWJSk/) instead of assigning the handlers directly to the inner `div`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$('divSelector').click(function()  
{  
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);  
});
```

Comment: Rather than attaching a separate event handler to each `div` with click, this would be an ideal situation to use event delegation in.  Just use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach a single event handler to the container that holds the `div`s instead of using `.click()` to add an event handler to each div.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need animation, then you can move the DOM elements around with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/japanick/jx945/

If you need animation, you can absolutely position the elements, and move them using the CSS top attribute in jQuery.animate().

Comment: And if you need animation then here is the example with images, which you can replace with your divs http://jsfiddle.net/rNzf7/